# search_update_totals() is not invoked / or search_cron() is not invoked

Tags: search

I don't know when, but this is new: in my Drupal 7 installation the indexing of search terms doesn't work anymore.

Here is a trace, but don't know how to solve it:
it seems that in /modules/search/search.module the search_cron() is not invoked anymore. And that is why necessary inserts in the database table search_total are ommitted.

Any ideas?

Thanks
Selim

Comment: Do you have either external cron running via a crontab or poorman's cron enabled via the admin.  See https://www.drupal.org/cron for more info.

Comment: I run cron externally on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

In some circunstances, you need to call `search_update_totals()` after indexing. The reason is that you need to make sure that it runs from the same location that you ran search_index, and after it.

In theory it is always called when you index using a cron job, but I am indexing with a drush command and I had to call it manually at the end. If the cron run failed it won't be called.